# What order should the Fairy Tail volumes/chapters be read in? And how to read labelling "Fairy Tail 465 - 400 Years"?

Tags: fairy-tail

I've watched up to episode 120 of the Fairy Tail anime and want to start to read the manga, while I finish the anime. I'm quite new to reading manga and know how to read them, it's just working out which one is the first one I find difficult.

I would really like to get the first manga (in the story) for a Christmas present but I don't know which one is first.

I started to read what was listed as the first one on a manga website (Labelled as Fairy Tail 465 - 400 Years) to check if it was and ended up reading the spoiler:

> That Natsu is Zeref's brother!

**Can someone please help me by telling me which manga I need to read first and what is the order of the others?**

And

If possible, **Can someone explain the labelling "Fairy Tail 465 - 400 Years"?** so that I know what to look out for in the future, to prevent spoiling it for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the chapters in order from Chapter 1 to the latest. On the majority of the websites they will put the latest characters (based on chapter number) towards the top of the page.

As for your second question: Fairy Tail 465 - 400 Years; means the that is chapter 465 of the series, and the title of that particular chapter is '400 years'.

As an FYI to you, there are several other Fairy Tail series that are pseudo-canon (or fully canon) related to the main story. Some of them are written by the same author of the core series. Just be warned that some of them have spoilers for historic events of the main series, but they are all really good.